# Regex Help - must be possible, i just can't get it to work

Tags: regex

EDIT - Since the XML angle seemed to be getting people off-course, i have changed the string that i am searching.  I know how to use XML technologies such as JAXB and Xpath/XQuery, i want to know if and how this is possible using REGEX only.

This has been driving me mad.  I have tried quite a few things, and have got close to what i want, but just can't nail it.

As a noddy example...

From this string

> ITEM id=1 a=1 wanted=YES x=24 ITEM id=2 a=1 b=2 wanted=NO y=25 ITEM id=3 c=3 wanted=YES x=25 z=26

I want to get the id's of each ITEM that has wanted=YES.  So the result in this case would be 1 and 3.

From what i have tried, the problem i am having is stopping my regex from looking beyond the current item as for item id=2 it is using the wanted=YES from item 3.  I have tried a couple of lookaheads (and behinds) but just can't get what i want.

I should also note that i want this as a single regex.  I know i could do things like just split out each item and then process that for wanted=Yes, but i want to know if it is possible using a single regex.  I am calling this regex from c# (.NET) so the regex could use the more fancy lookbehinds that .NET regex allows, but if possible i would prefer if it didn't so that it was more portable.

Thanks in advance (it looks like it should be simple, but is driving me mad),

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work (use negative lookahead for 'wanted'):

```
string s = "ITEM id=1 a=1 wanted=YES x=24 ITEM id=2 a=1 b=2 wanted=NO y=25 ITEM id=3 c=3 wanted=YES x=25 z=26";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, "id=([0-9]+)(.(?!wanted))*.wanted=yes", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
```

This assumes that the id always comes before the wanted.

Comment: Fantastic! Thankyou, THIS is what i was after (with a little altering it works on the xml-ish string that i gave in my original question too).  My attempts were pretty close to this, it seems i was missing the extra set of (.) that surround the lookahead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't be using regex to parse XML. This can be achieved using simple XPath. Depending on the language you use there are various XML libraries that support XPath.

Your sample XML is not valid, but here is a C# example (using LINQ-to-XML) with a valid one:

```
string s = "<root><item><id>1</id><x><wanted>YES</wanted></x></item><item><id>2</id><x><wanted>NO</wanted></x></item><item><id>3</id><x><wanted>YES</wanted></x></item></root>";
var xml = XElement.Parse(s);

var items = xml.XPathSelectElements("//item[descendant::wanted='YES']");

foreach (var item in items)
    Console.WriteLine((int)item.Element("id"));
```

Comment: Why do people do this?  Look thanks for your suggestion, BUT i did ask for a regex solution.  Saying that i shouldn't use regex for xml is wrong! regex is used for matching patterns in text, which is exactly what i want to do. If that happens to be xml then so be it.  Yes there are other ways to do xml, but there may be very good reasons for not using them.  One of those reasons may be that the xml i have is not valid (or strict xml) so that is why i want a regex solution please.

Comment: well the problem is that xml is complicated so if you want to cover all the cases it would be one huge regex, and very hard to read and test. And if your text is not valid xml then you should explain what is its structure - you obviously don't want to match just this string, but rather many **like** it. So define **like**. One easy way to define is to say it's XML - so I assumed it is.

Comment: I have now edited the example to remove xml from this issue. All i am interested in is how to solve this using a regex. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with regex. XML is not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

You will have to use something designed for parsing XML. The C# example on this page will probably help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx#Y586

Comment: Most implementation of regular expressions have no longer anything to do with regular languages. They are just confusingly named. That said, its still a bad idea to actually solve this problem with regular expressions, since there are better tools available, as you correctly state.

Comment: @Jens They still have a lot to do with Regular Languages. They can do a bit more but essentially all lookaheads and lookbacks do is allow you to run your strings through a finite number of finite state machines, instead of just one finite state machine. Perl regex is an exception though. It has nothing to do with anything other than Perl haha.

Comment: I have now edited the example to remove xml from this issue.  All i am interested in is how to solve this using a regex. thanks.